# Insert a template to child component in angular 6

Tags: angular

In this case, the app-child can not be changed, which means you can only operate the app-parent. My opinion is finding a way to insert the template in app-child, is there a function which like `Renderer2.insert(parent, newItem, childRef)` or another solution ?

Look at [https://stackblitz.com/edit/insert-template-to-child-component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/insert-template-to-child-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html) for detail.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-parent>
  <ng-template #childTemplate>
    how to insert this template in app-child
  </ng-template>
</app-parent>
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child>
  <!-- <ng-template #childTemplate>
    this is work, but I need to input the template in app-parent content
  </ng-template> -->
</app-child>
```

**child.component.html**

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="childTemplate"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can pass the template as an `@Input()` to the child

**parent.component.html**

```
<ng-template #childTemplate></ng-template>

<app-child [childTemplate]="childTemplate"></app-child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input()
childTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**child.component.html**

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="childTemplate"></ng-container>
```

---

You can use this same strategy to pass the template down multiple levels if needed.

---

More detailed information: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/#configurablecomponentswithtemplatepartialinputs

Comment: Thanks, it can work. But `@Input() childTemplate` and `@ContentChild('childTemplate') childTemplate` in app-child are some kind of repeated, I can not add any @Input in app-child for some reasons, could you find another way to resolve this ?

Comment: As I asked above, the app-child can not be changed, I could only do sth. in app-prent in my model. I thought the solution is to move the `<ng-template #childTemplate></ng-template>` into app-child, how do you think ?