# Angular - How to use ng-template in child component from Parent Component

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have a component called BaseComponent, and incomingRequestesComponent that inherit from BaseComponent.
in the HTML of baseComponent I need to put some templates to use them in components inherit from that BaseComponent.
BaseComponent:

```
export class BaseTimeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
// some code
}

<ng-template #selectField let-field="fieldName" let-record="recordId">
{{fieldName}} - {{record}}
</ng-template>
```

incoming-requests:

```
export class IncomingRequestsComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
// some code
}

<ng-container *ngIf="field.DataType == 3">
  <ng-container
   [ngTemplateOutlet]="selectTemplate"
   [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ fieldName: fieldName, recordId: recordId}"
  ></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

the issue is the template is not being passed to incoming-requests component event though there is no errors.
Is there any another way to do that??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a template to child component in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971873/insert-a-template-to-child-component-in-angular-6)

Comment: @kian not at all, I don't want to use selector of child component inside the parent component, because I will create many components inherit from the same parent

Comment: What’s your point of inheritance? AFAIK angular doesn’t support template inheritance. So, you have to extract it out. Use composition over inheritance. 1. Have a base class. 2. Have child components inherit the base class. 3. Extract common functionality into a separate common component and use inside your child.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are applied to a class but not to the class that extends the base class (see [this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zojztj?file=index.ts), should be called thrice, not twice).

Hence, you cannot provide a "base HTML file" to your child classes.

If you want to reference a template from a component, you will need to instanciate this component and its child, and use Angular to share data between them.